# Auto increment if 360 is not divisible by value

Tags: javascript, p5.js, modulo

I'm writing a drawing script that creates circular patterns using p5 javascript.
 
 
I want the number of sides in the polygon to be changed by pressing keys. I had all that working but I realized that the if 360 was divisible by the number of sides the patterns came out nicer. I thought to write a function that as the user increased or decreased sides, it would skip over values that were not divisible.
 
 
The keys still work but they are not always incrementing by one like the if statement is always coming out `false`. I tried putting the return in `else` but then that wouldn't return a value ever. 
What am I missing here?
Here's the javascript function:

```
function modCheck(num, dir){
  num = num + dir; //num is the number of sides | dir indicates if the sides should increase or decrease
  if(360 % num !== 0){
    modCheck(num, dir);
  }
    return num;
}
```

Here's the key press functions:

```
function keyPressed(){
  if((key === 'q' || key ===  'Q') && sides > 1 ) sides = modCheck(sides, -1);
  if((key === 'a' || key ===  'A') && sides < 360) sides = modCheck(sides, 1);
}
```

Comment: What does modCheck exactly do?

Comment: The idea is that it is supposed to check if 360 is divisible by the number of sides of the polygon (num). If it's not, I want it to keep changing the value until it is. The rest of the script draws mandalas. (not included) They look better if the number of sides is a factor of 360. I just want to skip the values that aren't divisible.

Comment: For example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45, 60, 72, 90, 120, 180, 360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your function is that you're not updating the `num` variable within the `if` statement. Here you have a working example:

```js
function modCheck(num, dir){
    num = num + dir; //num is the number of sides | dir indicates if the sides should increase or decrease
    if(360 % num !== 0){
      num = modCheck(num, dir);
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That was it. Thanks. Just one thing, your solution did not include the return. It needs that to work. Do you want to edit that and I'll check it as the solution?

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it helped you ^^

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.